# Window WPF Height is not bound to the model property

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

**Update:** This issue might be related to [Problems with binding to Window Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673600/problems-with-binding-to-window-height-and-width)

I'm trying to change the window height through the view model property. For some reason, it does not work.

This is the window class:

```
public partial class MyWindow
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MyWindowViewModel();

        // Does not work!
        // ((MainWindowViewModel) DataContext).Height = 50;

        // Works:
        //Height = 50;
```

MyWindow.xaml

```
<ctrls:MyBaseWindow x:Class="....MyWindow"
              ...
              Width="{Binding Width}"
              Height="{Binding Height}"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MyWindowViewModel}">
```

MyWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    ...

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _height, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Does your binding work for any other Property?

Comment: yes, I have ResizeMode also bound to the view model property and it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it inside my Visual Studio and it didn't worked when property SizeToContent of my window was set to "Height". When I removed it everything worked fine.

You should as well changed the order of the lines:

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new MyWindowViewModel();
```

to:

```
DataContext = new MyWindowViewModel();
InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: You should change the order of instructions in constructor of your window class - this should be the solution. I've editted my post to show that.

Comment: Actually, the changing of the order fixes original issue. But it looks like the binding is modified so I cannot change the window size by modifying the model properties.

Comment: And does your model implement properly INotifyChanged?

Comment: Yes, it is completely reactive (extends ReactiveObject). Actually, specifying two-way databinding for width and height solved the issue. Thank you for your help.