# Binding Window Size

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the Window's Width and Height using MVVM.

In my ViewModel i declare this Property:

```
public Size WindowSize
{
    get => _windowSize;
    set
    {
        _windowSize = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In my XAML i put this:

```
<Window
    Width="{Binding WindowSize.Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Height="{Binding WindowSize.Height, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ...>
```

If i first intialize it like `WindowSize = new Size(100, 600);` it works, but if i do the same at a later point in my ViewModel Code it only changes the Window's Width. I subscribed to the OnSizeChanged Event of the Window and found out that it is only called once when i set the Size and in the SizeChangedEventArgs only the NewSize.Width Property is updated. If i remove the Width Binding it works for the Height again. So it seems it fails to recognize a second Width or Height change. I already tried using two properties, one for width and one for height, but the behavior stayed the same.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with binding to Window Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673600/problems-with-binding-to-window-height-and-width)